# Laravel returning UnexpectedValueException

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having some problems with **scraping** function in Laravel.
The function is returning value of that scraped data, but below is showing a message like.

```
UnexpectedValueException: The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString()
```

What am I doing wrong here?

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Goutte;

class ScraperController extends Controller
{

    public function index(){
        $price = $this->getPrice();
        return $price;
    }

    public function getPrice(){

        $final_price = '';
        $crawler = Goutte::request('GET', 'https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Cable-Chompers-Animal-Protectors-Bite-Cable-Bite-Protector-Saver-For-Iphone-USB-Charger-Cable-Cute-Cartoon/32917115384.html');

            $crawler->filter('#j-sku-price')->each(function ($node) {
            $price = $node->text();
            print($price);
            });

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe is because `true` is boolean and `The Response content must be a string or object`

Comment: Could you show the full error trace? What line does the error happen?

Answer (score 1):

The `$price` variable in the index function is taken a boolean value. In your `getPrice()` you must return a `string` (or object) instead of `boolean`. Eg:

```
public function getPrice(){
    // ...

    return $final_price; // if the value of $final_price is what you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually when I delete  `return true` everything works fine. Thanks!